# A non-scrollable grid in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I looked at the `GridView` widget but its

> a scrollable, 2D array of widgets

I want the grid to occupy the maximum area permitted by the parent both horizontally and vertically. Or if there is some widget that expands while allowing us to specify rows and column. There must be cause I can think of several use cases.

Anyway, this is what I have at the moment,

```
class NumberButtonsGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(child: Row(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: Text("1"), flex: 1),
          Expanded(child: Text("2"), flex: 1),
          Expanded(child: Text("3"), flex: 1),
        ],), flex: 1),
        Expanded(child: Row(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: Text("4"), flex: 1),
          Expanded(child: Text("5"), flex: 1),
          Expanded(child: Text("6"), flex: 1),
        ],), flex: 1),
        Expanded(child: Row(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: Text("7"), flex: 1),
          Expanded(child: Text("8"), flex: 1),
          Expanded(child: Text("9"), flex: 1),
        ],), flex: 1),
        Expanded(child: Row(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: Text("."), flex: 1),
          Expanded(child: Text("0"), flex: 1),
          Expanded(child: Text("00"), flex: 1),
        ],), flex: 1),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this. It looks like a mess to me. What if I have to populate different widgets in individual cells? Thats going to be a disaster. This feels like making a table in `HTML` using `<div>`.

Comment: If GridView is working for you and you don't want it to scroll you can add `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to it.

Comment: Any Ability to expand to width of the container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to disable the scroll of the GridView/ListView, add:

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

GridView/ListView has an auto-expanding behavior so you need to set the **width** of the parent widget if your widget is set to `Axis.vertical` and vise-versa.

And you can use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * number` to set the width of the GridView according to screen size.